# The probability of two dice both returning even numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm fairly certain that the probability of both dice returning an even number is $1/4$.

I got this by saying that since these are independent events, with each die returning an even number being $1/2$, then the probability of both being even is $1/2 \times 1/2 = 1/4$.

Further, there are 36 outcomes, and all possible even number combinations are $(2, 2), (2, 4), (2, 6), (4, 4), (4, 6), (6, 6), (6, 4), (6, 2), (4, 2)$. There are nine of them and $9/36 = 1/4$

What I can't seem to get over, is that there are an equal number of odd and even numbers, so, why is the answer not $1/2$?

I know that it's not one half, but I can't explain why.

Comment: It’s essentially the same as the fact that the probability of getting two heads when you flip two fair coins is $\frac12\cdot\frac12=\frac14$, not $\frac12$. If it were $\frac12$, the same reasoning would tell you that the probability of getting two heads would be $\frac12$, and $\frac12+\frac12=1$, so the probability of getting one head and one tail would be $0$ — which is clearly not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I can't seem to get over, is that there are an equal number of odd and even numbers, so, why is the answer not 1/2 ?

Because they are not complementary events.   There is another possibility.

The probability that both dice show even numbers is: $1/4$

The probability that both dice show odd numbers is: $1/4$

The probability that one die shows even and the other shows odd is: $1/2$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking of pairs of outcomes, incorporate the two dice into one, more complicated probability space.  It is true that there are equally many odd and even score *for a single die*.  But, with two dice scores being viewed as one outcome to a new, more complicated experiment, we have an exhaustive and mutually exclusive list of four events: (die 1: odd, die 2: odd), (even, odd), (odd, even), and (even, even).  These events are equiprobable, so each has probability $1/4$.  Notice that the probability of having an even score on *at least one die* is not less (actually, greater) than $1/2$.